# Strange ampersand shape in italics

Tags: fonts, symbols, typography

I'm trying to use the `&` symbol in the bib file. The following is my code:

```
booktitle = {Design, Automation {\&} Test in Europe Conference {\&} Exhibition},
```

The output is :

[image]

Is this common? Or do I do something wrong?

Comment: You get an ampersand in the current font.

Comment: Is your question about why the "ampersand" symbol looks quite different when it's typeset in italics than when it's typeset in the upright/Roman shape?

Comment: @egreg, do you mean it should be like that?

Comment: That's how the font designer wanted it to be in the italic font.

Comment: @FihopZz The "&" is a transformed form of Latin word "et" (and). In your example it is much more visible than in current font.

Comment: I'd also tie the words _in_ and _Europe:_ `in~Europe`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments: what you're getting as the output of an `\&` with your current font (Computer Modern) is simply one of many renditions of the symbol called an [ampersand.](http://www.typophile.com/node/39812) Traditionally, type designers have always taken a lot more liberties with *that* glyph than with, say, a plain `a`. That's been a custom for several centuries, which is why today we have thousands of ampersand versions in various degrees of fanciness. Enough to even justify writing entire books dedicated to that one glyph, as, e.g., typographer Jan Tschichold has done.

[image]

Needless to say, your ›problem‹ is not restricted (or related) to bibliographies...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
Design, Automation \& Test in Europe Conference \& Exhibition\\
\emph{Design, Automation \& Test in Europe Conference \& Exhibition}

\fontfamily{qcs}\selectfont
Design, Automation \& Test in Europe Conference \& Exhibition\\
\emph{Design, Automation \& Test in Europe Conference \& Exhibition}

\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont
Design, Automation \& Test in Europe Conference \& Exhibition\\
\emph{Design, Automation \& Test in Europe Conference \& Exhibition}

\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont
Design, Automation \& Test in Europe Conference \& Exhibition\\
\end{document}
```

[image]